# Why doesn't SSIS ftp task receive file?

Tags: ssis, ftp

I'm running an FTP task inside of SSIS to receive a file and the task executes successfully yet no file is returned to the local folder that I specified. Where did the file go? How can I make the FTP task download a file to the location that I need it at?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the FTP connection Manager and File Manager set up, and other stuff correct as per the list [here (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179917(SQL.90).aspx)

- operation
- "OverwriteFileAtDestination"
- IsASCIITransfer

I've had this problem when I first used an FTP task, but can't recall exactly what I had to do. Double check every setting and also make sure a plain old command line FTP works too to ensure it's only an SSIS issue

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have an expression or variable set up that puts the file in another folder?  This might explain why the file is not where you expect it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check to make certain that you're not pulling from a UNIX/Linux box, as this is a known issue.

Comment: Hi, please could you explain the known issue? I've the same problem that arised out of the box yesterday... and the remote FTP Server was changed but I have no other information.